# Create an aggregate list of values and number of occurrences in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given the following documents:

```
[
  {
    _id: "N0001",
    name: "Bruce Lee",
    skills: ["karate", "jiu jitsu"],
  },
  {
    _id: "N0002",
    name: "Bruce Dee",
    skills: ["karate", "tae kwon do"],
  },
  {
    _id: "N0003",
    name: "Bruce See",
    skills: ["aikido", "jiu jitsu"],
  },
  {
    _id: "N0004",
    name: "Deuce Lee",
    skills: ["karate", "judo"],
  },
]
```

I would like to get the following:

```
{
  karate: 3,
  jiu jitsu: 2,
  tae kwon do: 1,
  judo: 1,
  aikido: 1,
}
```

Now I could get the above with some sort of script like the following:

```
const uniqueSkills = db.fighters.distinct('skills');
console.log(
  Object.fromEntries(
    uniqueSkills.map(
      async m => [m, await db.fighters.find({ skills: m }).length]
    )
  )
)
```

But I'd really like to keep this whole thing within the aggregation framework and not use a node runtime to make this query repeatedly, and I'm completely lost as to how to do that. Of note, the set of skills is finite, but unknown, so I can't start from a known list of skills and just hardcode those into the query itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is as follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$skills"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$skills",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      skills: {
        "$addToSet": {
          k: "$_id",
          v: "$count"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$skills"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The output using your sample input is:

```
{
  "aikido": 1,
  "jiu jitsu": 2,
  "judo": 1,
  "karate": 3,
  "tae kwon do": 1
}
```

Here we are:

1. `$unwind`ing the `skills` array to get individual entries.
2. `$group`ing those skills together to get the count
3. `$group`ing those groups together to get all of the entries into a single document
4. Reshaping the document using `$replaceRoot`.

Steps three and four are designed to make use of [the `$arrayToObject` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/).

See how it works in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XEUnmdnosuE).

I'm quite certain there are other ways to do this. Also as a word of caution, this operation will be resource intensive as your data set grows, but that is just a natural consequence of how an analytical operation like this will have to run against that schema.